# Replicating the behaviour of setattr and delattr from dataclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

Whilst watching Raymond Hettinger's talk from PyCon 2018, [Dataclasses: The code generator to end all code generators - PyCon 2018](https://youtu.be/T-TwcmT6Rcw?t=1869) an example of how dataclasses implement setattr and delattr on frozen dataclasses was provided:

```py
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if type(self) is cls or name in ('name', 'address', 'zip_code', 'account_balance', 'active_orders'):
        raise FrozenInstanceError(f'Cannot assign to field {name!r}')
    super(cls, self).__setattr__(name, value)

def __delattr__(self, name):
    if type(self) is cls or name in ('name', 'address', 'zip_code', 'account_balance', 'active_orders'):
        raise FrozenInstanceError(f'Cannot delete field {name!r}')
    super(cls, self).__delattr__(name)
```

Is it possible to replicate the behaviour of calling `super()` inside `setattr` and `delattr` without dataclasses to emulate immutability?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: ... you have the code right there? What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: @martineau If I run this without using data classes I get an error that `cls` is not defined, so my question is how do data classes have access to `cls` inside these functions and is it possible to replicate this without the use of a data class?

Comment: That's just an alias to the class name. It isn't complete code, If you are using Python 3, you can just use `super()` with no arguments anyway, or if say, you are defining `class Foo: ...` the equivalent `super(Foo, self).__whatever__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out in a comment, you *can* replicate the behavior using the built-in `super()` function, however you *don't* need to pass it any arguments (in Python 3 at least).
Example:

```
class Class:
    class FrozenInstanceError(Exception): pass

    fieldnames = 'name', 'address', 'zip_code', 'account_balance', 'active_orders'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__setattr__('account_balance', 0)  # Bypasses this class' __setattr__().

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if isinstance(self, Class) and name in self.fieldnames:
            raise self.FrozenInstanceError(f'Cannot assign to field {name!r}')
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        if isinstance(self, Class) and name in self.fieldnames:
            raise self.FrozenInstanceError(f'Cannot delete field {name!r}')
        super().__delattr__(name)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    inst = Class()
    print(inst.account_balance)  # -> 0
    try:
        inst.account_balance = 1000000
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)  # -> Cannot assign to field 'account_balance'
    else:
        print('Error: Somehow assigned value to "account_balance" field')

    try:
        inst.something_else = 42  # OK, not a field name.
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)  # -> 'Error: Wasn't allowed to create "something_else" field'
    else:
        print('Successfully created "something_else" attribute.')  # Prints.

    try:
        del inst.account_balance
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)  # -> Cannot delete field 'account_balance'
    else:
        print('Error: Somehow deleted protected "account_balance" field')

    try:
        del inst.something_else
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)  # -> 42
    else:
        print('Successfully deleted "something_else" attribute.')  # Prints.
```

Comment: My take on why you shouldn't use `isinstance()` for this is because a subclass might not have the frozen trait, yet may delegate to the parent's `__*attr()__`.  Hence the "only this class and no subclasses" check done by dataclasses.

Comment: @Alastair: Your take is a mistake. Using `isinstance()` is fine here since subclasses can define their own frozen traits by simply setting their own `fieldnames` class attribute to something else. It's almost never a good idea to do explicit type-checking in Python (such as what's shown in the OP's question).